# Is it correct to use "in developing" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use "in developing" in the following sentence?

The proportion of men to women in developing gastric lesions was 3 to 1.

Comment: No, there is no need for the "in".

Comment: Perhaps "developing" descibes the lesions, not the people who have them, as in "a developing lesion". It's unclear without context what the sentence is trying to say. Is it "the proportion of men to women **with** gastric lesions"?

Comment: @JasonBassford - You mean "lesions"? And what about "the proportion of men to women developing gastric lesions"?

Comment: That sentence has at least 3 subtly different interpretations . The difference in meaning would be made much clearer if one of the following constructions where used instead: (1) *the proportion of men to women **who develop** gastric lesions* (2) *the proportion of men to women **who have** gastric lesions* (3) *the proportion of men to women **who have developing** gastric lesions.*

Comment: @NIck08 Indeed. That's an interesting typo. I've deleted my original comment and posted a corrected version. The new sense you suggest would be covered by (4) *the proportion of men to women **who are developing** gastric lesions*.